# How to simulate SVG `pointer-events: bounding-box` in Firefox & Safari

Tags: css, firefox, svg, safari, pointer-events

I have an SVG with nested SVGs inside of it that are wrapped inside various `<a>` tags. I would like the entire nested SVG to activate the link (i.e. be clickable), but it seems I cannot use the CSS property `pointer-events: bounding-box` as that value isn't supported by Safari & Firefox. (This works great in Chrome, however).

**What other approach could I use to simulate this behavior in these browsers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cover each SVG with a transparent `<rect>` and wrap that with the link element.

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">

  <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <svg x="50" y="50" width="200" height="100">
      <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" fill="red"/>
    </svg>
  </a>
  
</svg>

<svg width="300" height="200">

  <svg x="50" y="50" width="200" height="100">
    <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
  <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="100" fill="transparent"/>
  </a>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: I ended up placing both the SVG and transparent rectangle inside the anchor, so I could reference them via CSS more easily (I wanted mouseover effects on the underlying SVG). So like this:

`<a><svg></svg><rect fill="transparent" /></a>`